# Eclipse RCP View resize programmatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a requirement in Eclipse RCP where I need to resize the views within my perspective, like select a particular view and press left arrow key to shrink it in width (simultaneously increase the width of the neighbor view) and same with right, top  and bottom keys. I have been browsing for a while now to understand how we can resize a view programatically. I am sure eclipse has a command for this, but I am unable to find it. If I get this command than I can hook the hotkeys to this command or add a key binding.

Thanks in advance!

Editing my earlier comment to add additional details.

There is a context menu item called size (right click on any view name)  -> rightcick -> Size -> top|bottom|left|right. These menu items are contributed by eclipse itself. But they are not always visible, we should be configuring the preference store in order to get this, I am unable to find this setting.Upon selecting either of the options there will be selectable object occuring in between the views (depending on the selected menu) and now on click of left or right | top or bottom keys we will be able to resize the view.

Please see the attached image. I got this image from a developer who has left the organization now.[View Resize screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2HvR.png). [Image of the selectable object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anx3P.png)

Comment: Actually I don't think Eclipse has a command for this. It just done with mouse listeners in the part sash container `SashLayout`.

Comment: Hello greg, Thanks for the response. Can you please see my edited comments, does this help to give any hint ?

Comment: I believe that menu image is from Eclipse 3 and doesn't exist in Eclipse 4.

Comment: So we have any way to call those commands in Eclipse 3 ?

Comment: No idea. Eclipse 3.8 is now 5 years old and obsolete.

Comment: Thanks Greg, anybody else who can help me with this problem ?